# Batch Command to Mux Multiple Video and Subtitle Files in Sequence to Different Filenames

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ffmpeg, batch-file

On Windows 10, what's a simple command to to mux multiple video and subtitle files in sequence to different sequential filenames using ffmpeg? I'm manually doing

```
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 1.mp4" -i "moviename part 1.srt" -c copy "temp01.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 2.mp4" -i "moviename part 2.srt" -c copy "temp02.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 3.mp4" -i "moviename part 3.srt" -c copy "temp03.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 4.mp4" -i "moviename part 4.srt" -c copy "temp04.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 5.mp4" -i "moviename part 5.srt" -c copy "temp05.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 6.mp4" -i "moviename part 6.srt" -c copy "temp06.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 7.mp4" -i "moviename part 7.srt" -c copy "temp07.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 8.mp4" -i "moviename part 8.srt" -c copy "temp08.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 9.mp4" -i "moviename part 9.srt" -c copy "temp09.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 10.mp4" -i "moviename part 10.srt" -c copy "temp10.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 11.mp4" -i "moviename part 11.srt" -c copy "temp11.mkv"
    .
    .
    .
    ffmpeg -i "moviename part 99.mp4" -i "moviename part 99.srt" -c copy "temp99.mkv"
```

for now, but it's tiring. I found this command that muxes the files

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.mp4" -i "%%~na.srt" -c copy "%%~na.mkv"
```

but it outputs the same filenames **moviename part 1.mkv**, **moviename part 2.mkv**, **moviename part 3.mkv** and so forth instead of **temp01.mkv**, **temp02.mkv**, **temp03.mkv**, etc. like I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's a simple command to to mux multiple video and subtitle files in sequence?

Use `for /l`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in (1,1,99) do (
  set _count=00%%a
  ffmpeg -i "moviename part %%a.mp4" -i "moviename part %%a.srt" -c copy "temp!_count:~-2!.mkv"
)
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: I'm running into problems where the "for" command is messing up the order of the files. It's processing part 1, 10, 11, etc then part 2, 20, 21, etc instead of ascending. And the command works up to **temp08.mkv** then asks to overwrite **temp01.mkv**, **temp02.mkv** and so on. But I still up voted the answer (even though it won't show) since it partially works. Thanks.

Comment: @joetex72 Answer updated.

Comment: This works David, thanks. Can it be modified to use wild cards? Because sometimes **moviename** has additional characters and isn't always an exact match.

Comment: Not easily. I would be tempted to fix up the filenames first ...